# Java PreparedStatement Error: "Cannot resolve query parameter '2' and '3'"

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am tyring to override a borrowBook interface. What is wrong with my code? Why there are errors such: Cannot resolve query parameter '2' and Cannot resolve query parameter '3'.

```
@Override
    public void borrowBook(int bookId) throws SQLException {

        Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/library11", "postgres", "123");

        try(conn) {
            String sql = "UPDATE books SET isavailable = false WHERE bookid = ? AND isavailable = true";
            PreparedStatement stmn = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            stmn.setInt(1, bookId);

            int rowsAffected = stmn.executeUpdate();

            if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                sql = "INSERT INTO loans (memberid, bookid, loandate) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                stmn = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                stmn.setInt(1, this.getUserId());
                stmn.setInt(2, bookId); // Parameter 2 (error)
                stmn.setDate(3, currentDate); // Parameter 3 (error)

                stmn.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("You have successfully borrowed the book!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("This book is not available");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e)  {
            System.out.println("connection error: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("could not close the connection: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are these errors actual exceptions being thrown at runtime? Do you have the stacktrace?

Comment: No. I do not have anything like this

Comment: Can you show the debug logs?

Comment: In your code there is no point in having that `sql` variable. Just pass the strings directly to the `prepareStatement` methods, or define constants for them.

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles and runs just fine.

Your problem is that the editor window in IntelliJ IDEA is showing a red underline for the two lines you mention. This is because you've defined a String variable `sql` at the start which contains only one parameter placeholder (i.e. only one "?") and then you've reset the same variable to a different String, one which now contains three "?". IntelliJ IDEA gets confused by this, and thinks your `sql` variable is the one you've defined first, so it thinks the statement only has 1 parameter, and complains about parameters 2 and 3.

To work around this issue, define a different variable to hold your second SQL string. Better still, heed Mark Rotteveel's comment: just pass the strings directly to the `prepareStatement` methods, or define constants for them.

This is a workaround for an IDE problem, not an actual JDBC error in your code.